# User permission denied to follow Softlink in root's home

Tags: permissions, symbolic-link, chown

I have a directory containing a load of files and would like to access and using it as user, via a Softlink in the `/opt` directory, but keeping it in the `/root` directory:

```
root@computer:~# ll myDirectory_v11
root@computer:~# drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Jun 25 12:45  myDirectory_v11
```

Now I create a Softlink:

```
root@computer:~# ln -s /root/myDirectory_v11 /opt/myDirectory
```

To gain access and run software inside I change the owner, the like:

```
root@computer:~# chown -R myUser:myUser /opt/myDirectory
```

This returns no error and listing it inside the /opt confirms, that all went well. The owner changed correctly.

After logging out from root and trying to change into the /opt/myDirectory, I receive a `bash: cd: /opt/myDirectory: Keine Berechtigung`.

In Centos this was never an issue. How to make it accessible for the myUser?

I tried a lot of things, e.g. using `-hR` flag for prohibition of dereferencing or tried `sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=0` to no avail.
Has it something to do with some sticky-bit? If so, how to overcome the problem?

Comment: Likely because `/root` doesn't have execute permission for anyone except `root`

Comment: Thx. But if root gives access to one folder for one user, why isn't it possible to access it for the user? How to allow the user to use the folder and contents?

Comment: Because changing  ownership on the sym-link don't change  ownership on the file/directory the sym-link points to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `/root` is missing the execute permission. If the upper folders do not allow the execution, you cannot look inside the sub-folders (even if you have permissions for this folders)

So add execute permission to the root folder with:

```
$ sudo chmod a+X /root
```

And it will work.

Word of advice, don’t store anything in the `/root` folder! There is no good reason for it. It is the home of the root user and should not be used for anything else. So after you tested that it works, remove the permission with `sudo chmod go-X /root/`

Comment: This. And `chown -R`will not follow symlinks.

Comment: Accepted. Where would you store software? I created a symlink to avoid specific version numbers in directory names and afterwards to be forced to reconfigure depending stuff over and over again. So my idea was to simply bending the file pointer... ;-)

Comment: `/usr/local/…` is the usual place, where you store custom modifications. Use the `bin` for executables, `lib`, `var`, and `share` as used in the default `/usr/`. If you need or want to store everything in one folder, then `/opt` is a good place.

Comment: @SimonSudler
Tried, worked, removed permissions. Moved package away from root and stuffed into /usr/local. Thank you very much for your assistance!